# Help Understanding/Adapting the Definition of Beamer's 'lecture' Command

Tags: beamer, macros, robust-commands

Beamer's 'lecture' command has been a great way for me to have all my lecture notes in one document, but typeset only the segments that I need for any given day/week of class. Ultimately I would like to try and adapt this command to other document classes (currently it is very embedded in the 'beamer' class).

I would consider myself an advanced TeX user, but a novice when it comes to advanced programming (I've put together a few of my own `class' files, but nothing too advanced).

Here's what I found in 'beamerbasesection.sty':

```
%
% Lecture Definitions
%
\newif\ifbeamer@inlecture
\beamer@inlecturetrue

\newcommand{\beamer@if@in@clist@TF}[2]{%
  \def\beamer@if@in@clist@aux##1,#2,{}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@nil
    \expandafter\beamer@if@in@clist@aux\expandafter,#1,{}{},#2,\@nil
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}

\newcounter{lecture}
\renewcommand\thelecture{\@arabic\c@lecture}
\let\insertlecturenumber=\thelecture
\newrobustcmd*\lecture{\@dblarg\beamer@lecture}
\long\def\beamer@lecture[#1]#2#3{%
  \beamer@savemode
  \mode<all>%
  \refstepcounter{lecture}%
  \def\beamer@currentlecturelabel{#3}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\beamer@currentlecturelabel
  \def\beamer@lecturename{#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortlecturename{#1}%
  \ifx\beamer@onlylecture\@empty
  \else
    \expandafter\beamer@if@in@clist@TF\expandafter\beamer@onlylecture
      \expandafter{\beamer@currentlecturelabel}%
      {\beamer@inlecturetrue}%
      {\beamer@inlecturefalse}%
  \fi
  \beamer@atbeginlecture
  \beamer@resumemode
}
```

So how does this command work its magic? When I type `\includeonlylecture{foo}`, how does it know to grab only the text after `\lecture[]{}{foo}` and before the next 'lecture' command? Thanks for any insight you can give!

Just for completeness I've included a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\includeonlylecture{foo}

\begin{document}
\lecture[]{}{notfoo1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Text1}
This frame won't show.
\end{frame}


\lecture[]{}{foo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello, World!}
Greetings.
\end{frame}


\lecture[]{}{notfoo2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Text2}
This frame won't show either.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The secret is actually all in the `\mode` command so you'd have to include that in your implementation.  TeX goes into a "gobbling" mode whereby it ignores everything except certain commands, one of which is `\lecture`.  When it encounters the lecture it is looking for then it stops gobbling and resumes normal processing.  So you'd need to copy over the stuff for `\mode` as well.

Comment: @LoopSpace, thank you! As per your suggestion I've been reading (in the beamer user guide) about beamer's implementation of `\mode`, which is different than anything I've dived into before. If you have any other suggestions for reading or examples I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, on reflection I think I'm wrong. The lecture command in beamer *does* process everything, but it discards the result unless in the right lecture. I found this to be incredibly slow so I modified it in my lectures to use `\mode` which is much faster.  I have a version of `\mode` for non-beamer documents if that is an acceptable route.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be possible to use my extension of pgfpages to do the process-and-discard variant.

Comment: @LoopSpace, I would be very interested in learning more about your non-beamer implementation of `\mode`. Where can I find it?

Comment: It's part of a larger package, but it is a separate file so could be used separately.  You can find it at https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet/blob/master/internetmodes.code.tex